# How to select expo release-channel in the mobile app?

Tags: expo

I can't find my newly published "QA" release channel in the expo mobile client app.

I've been using the default channel to publish my expo app while developing, and that works great.  Now I want to test the same code in a QA environment.  I published it successfully with `expo publish --release-channel qa`.  I can even see it was published when I run `expo publish:history`.

But I can't see it in the expo mobile app so I'm not sure how to load it up and test it..

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so much a solution as a workaround, but if I create an expo url like this in my mobile browser address bar, android will open it in the expo app:

```
https://expo.io/@myaccount/My-Project-Name?release-channel=qa
```